# Will speed/cadence sensor work with 650c bicycle

Tags: wheels, hybrid-bike, sensor

I plan to use speed/cadence sensor, however my bicycle wheel size is 650c.

I guess, there are no problem about cadence.

But for speed (wheel speed sensor), will it work correctly?

Comment: I've been using cyclometers for about 30 years, and I've never encountered one that wasn't adjustable in terms of wheel diameter.  In fact, it's recommended that you measure your wheel circumference (by rolling the bike one full wheel rev on a flat surface) and input that, to account for minor differences in tire brands, etc.

Answer (score 5):

With common digital cycle computers, wheel size shouldn't be an issue as you can configure them to work for any reasonable tire size on the market.

Comment: The last cycle computer I published was a Cateye. The leaflet which came with it included a list of rolling diameters for "standard" sizes. (Wider tyres are also taller)

Answer (score 0):

Yes; the computer will require you to enter the tire's circumference.